# How do I assign a certain value from an object to a long variable?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Example:

```
long a;
BoundedCounter e;
```

So I want to assign the value of the private variable counter in the class to a.

```
a=e;
```

Tried using this:

```
long int & operator=(long b)
{
    b=counter;
    return b;
}
```

and

```
long int & operator=(long b, BoundedCounter &a)
{
   b=a.getCounter();
   return b;
}
```

Which return a compile error:

> cannot convert `BoundedCounter' to`
>   long int' in assignment

and

> `long int& operator=(long int, BoundedCounter&)' must be a nonstatic member function

How do I define an operator= outside of the class which will work when the left side is a normal variable and not an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator=` is unsuitable here as the left-hand side of the assignment is a primitive type (and you cannot define `operator=` for primitive types). Try giving `BoundedCounter` an `operator long`, e.g.:

```
class BoundedCounter
{
public:
    // ...
    operator long() const
    {
        return counter;
        // or return getCounter();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is converting from a `BoundedCounter` to a `long` so you need to define a conversion (cast) operator from `BoundedCounter` to `long`:

```
class BoundedCounter {
private:
    long a_long_number;
public:
    operator long() const {
        return a_long_number;
    }
};
```

The assignment operator that you had defined would allow you to assign a `long` value to an instance of the `BoundedCounter` class which is the opposite of what you are trying to do.